# jQuery-ui issue: .slider("value") is returning the slider itself instead of the slider's value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to get the current value of a jQuery-UI [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) in a JavaScript function and it is not working. If I do

```
  $("#someParticularDOMObject").find(".slider").first()
```

in FireBug, it returns the correct

```
  [ div.slider ]
```

that I'm trying to select, but when I ask it for

```
  $("#someParticularDOMObject").find(".slider").first().slider("value")
```

it doesn't return the value; it just returns the `div` again:

```
  [ div.slider ]
```

Any thoughts as to why this wouldn't work/what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I get the same behavior in Safari.

PPS: I am using jQuery version 1.5.1, but could update to current release if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to access the current value of the slider, one method can be accesed from anywhere in the script (after the slider has been initially bound) like so:

```
$("#mySlider").slider('option', 'value');
```

Or from within any of the slider events:

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // for example purposes only, this alert would be very annoying
        alert(ui.value); 
    }
});
```

I find that the latter tends to give more accurate values at times, but possibly only when it comes to decimals.

Other options, events and methods can be found at the bottom of the page from that link you gave.

Comment: I was under the impression `$("#mySlider").slider('option', 'value');` and `$("#mySlider").slider('value');` were basically synonyms. But in any case, I get the same problem either way.

I'm decidedly _not_ inside a slider event, so I can't go for your other option.

Comment: Then again, after 5 minutes of minor refactoring, it turned out there was no reason I _couldn't_ be inside a slider event.

I still would appreciate an answer as to why `.slider('option', 'value')` wasn't working just to satisfy curiosity, but from a pragmatic, get-'er-done perspective, problem solved, thank you!

Comment: You were right about the synonym part, btw. Not sure as to why it isn't working for you, but I knocked up this quick demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/Dn4yS/), which shows that it can work. Are you sure you were trying to retrieve the values after the slider had been initialised?